# sun cc doesn't find some libraries when instructed to compile in 64 bit

Tags: c++, linkage

To illustrate:

```
# CC -xO3 -lssl
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
main                                /opt/sunstudio12.1/prod/lib/crt1.o
__udivdi3                           /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
__umoddi3                           /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
# CC -xO3 -m64 -lssl
ld: fatal: library -lssl: not found
ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to a.out
```

I also note that:

```
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/csw/gcc4/lib/64
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64
<empty line>
```

Hence, according to [this page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19205-01/819-5262/aeudd/index.html), ld's path lookup should be identical for both cases, which it most obviously isn't...

does anyone know how to get around this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have 64bit SSL library installed?

Comment: Does it matter? It should be able to link against a 32bit SSL library...

Comment: Yes, it matters. If you want to compile a 64bit executable, you need 64bit versions of all the required libraries.

Comment: Oddly enough, libssl isn't even present in the directory in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which means Solaris somehow references to another location, in a manner which discerns between 32 and 64 bits... How and where this takes place I couldn't figure out...

Comment: OK, I'll make sure I have a 64 bit version and update on the matter, thanks.